# What does _dopr mean

Tags: c++, c, gdb, coredump

I have a gdb be crashed dump having crashed at dopr

What does this do ?
I have not defined this function and not using calling anywhere. Is is libc function ?

```
[Switching to thread 1 (Thread 5339)]#0  0x00000000005f0937 in _dopr ()
(gdb) bt
#0  0x00000000005f0937 in _dopr ()
#1  0x00000000000003ff in ?? ()
#2  0x000000000111c3b0 in ?? ()
#3  0x00007fced1fe1f80 in ?? ()
#4  0x0000000000000000 in ?? ()
```

Comment: It's likely some internal function in some library (libc has _doprnt, maybe it's related). However you've got a bigger issue, it looks like stack corruption.

Comment: It's strange gdb printed the name `_dopr`, but didn't print any file that symbol came from. If it has a name, it must have read it from somewhere and it normally prints where.

Comment: then what should I do to get more info ?

Comment: run your application with valgrind, this could tell you where effectively your application is writing bad things.

Comment: I had already done that but valgrind log was clear it was not having any memory heap or other corruption :(.

Comment: In the case of stack corruption, it might make sense to check for a buffer overrun.

Comment: To get more useful symbols in the stack trace, compile and link the code with the `-g` flag.  However, I think you probably have some code trampling over the stack - as others suggested - and that is why you are not seeing symbols.

Comment: @Jonathan Leffler and what about library . I am using many library like ssl. does I need to recompile them with -g ?

Comment: If you're going to be using gdb and compiling with -g, remember to also install the debug symbols for any libraries you're using. A lot of Linux distributions tend to strip them and keep them in separate packages to save space, and without them, you might as well be disassembling everything and working off the machine code!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments _dopr isn't your problem.  What you are looking at is stack corruption, and again, in the comments, a buffer overflow is the most likely problem.

Assuming you are compiling your application with gcc, add the option:

```
-fstack-protector-all
```

to your compile and link options.  This stick a couple of extra sentinel bits around the stack, and when your buffer overflow occurs, in gdb you'll see a much more useful 'stack smashing detected' message, along with the stack trace of your application before it actually destroys the stack.